# excel Search and list

Tags: excel, search

i am having an issue with Excel. What I am trying to do is have a user input an area and it list the cities in that area with a ; inbetween each city. Basically the data only has 2 columns. So you can think of it as Metro Area|Cities for the columns. so each city in that metro area list it.

`eg.
metro|City
LA|West Covina
LA|Glendale
LA|Irwindale
NY|Queens
NY|Brooklyn`

I would like to have another sheet where a user inputs a Metro area and in the cities go in the cell next to it seperated with ;. so for NY it would bring up Queens;Brooklyn.

Can someone provide help for this.

Comment: Do you need a formula or would a macro be O.K. ??

Comment: I would prefer a formula. But a macro might be fine. Trying to make it as easy as possible for multiple people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say our data in `Sheet1` is like:

[image]

In cell **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!B2,"")
```

and copy down.  In `Sheet2` cell **A1**, the user enters the metro area and in `Sheet2` cell **B1** we enter the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,Sheet1!C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: So this TEXTJOIN doesn't seem to be a function in my version of excel 2013.

Comment: This did help me though. I have figured it out with a few tweaks to your original idea.